# how to copy data of a DB from one django app to another app

Tags: django, django-database

I have Django app, one is in local machine and other is in production server after deploying in production server i see i lost all my local data lost so I want to know how I can copy all my data from db and paste into production server so is there any way please share how to do it

Comment: If you use SQLite on both (which I do not recommend), you can simply copy the DB file over. If you use a SQL server on the production server, you can use fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dump db on local machine:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > db.json
```

Load db on production server:

```
python3 manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am wondering what If i have to copy my production data into in local machine  is there any way to do that

Comment: In the same way, you can dump db on production server and load it on local machine using same above commands.

Comment: then how i can download my db file form heroku production server